# Mysqli_real_escape_string() or addslashes() in a forum context

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm making a forum in php and MySql, so I need to insert and select data from my data base. I'm using mysqli to connect to my db. Something like this:

```
$link=mysqli_connect("fake_server", "fake_user", "fake_pass", "fake_db");

$user=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['user']);
$pass=hash("sha256", mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['pass']));

$combo=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE user='$user' AND pwd='$pass'"));
if($combo==0){
        // ERROR
} else {
        // CORRECT
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

The problem is the next one:
Everybody say that mysqli_real_escape_string() is MUCH better than addslashes() for insert, but I want users can use single and double quotes in their topics. Myqsli_real_escape_string() removes them but addslashes() doesn't. What can I do in this context?

Comment: *"but I want users can use these symbols in their topics."* - which symbols are those?

Comment: Obviously, for preventing SQL injections.

Comment: you should modify your question then, as well as stating which quotes. Single quotes, double quotes, both? it could have a bearing on potential answers.

Comment: @Fred-ii-You're right, thanks.

Comment: Are you using `PDO`, `mysql_`, `mysqli_`, or another driver to connect to your db? Can you post a sample of the PHP you currently are using?

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` shouldn't be removing any quotes, it will just escape any that could cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use prepared statements, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php. In the future please provide your code in your question. Here's how you can use your current code with prepared statements:

```
$link=mysqli_connect("fake_server", "fake_user", "fake_pass", "fake_db");
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=hash("sha256", $_POST['pass']); 
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE user = ? AND pwd = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);
$combo=mysqli_fetch_array($stmt->execute());
if($combo==0){
        // ERROR
} else {
        // CORRECT
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

Further reading on the topic:

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
[mysqli or PDO - what are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1:_Prepared_Statements_.28Parameterized_Queries.29
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: But, connecting to the db by mysqli* although using PDO queries is also good for protecting against injections or is more secure connecting by PDO?

Comment: They both can use parameterized queries and I haven't heard an argument for one over the other. I'll update answer with additional links on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameterized query with [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) and forget worrying about escaping your queries.

**Edit**

Your test code:

```
$link=mysqli_connect("fake_server", "fake_user", "fake_pass", "fake_db");

$user=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['user']);
$pass=hash("sha256", mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['pass']));

$combo=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE user='$user' AND pwd='$pass'"));
if($combo==0){
        // ERROR
} else {
        // CORRECT
}
mysqli_close($link);
```

The PDO version:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=fake_server;dbname=fake_db', 'fake_user', 'fake_pass');

$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE user='?' AND pwd='?'");
$query->execute(array($_POST('user'), hash('sha256', $_POST('pass')));

if ($combo = $query->fetch ()) {
  // CORRECT
  // $combo would contain an array containing your select fields
} else {
  // ERROR
}
```

Comment: Yeah, ah... I've read the tutorial you attached but this is the first time I work with PDO, so... Could you put an example, please? Then, I'll understand it.

Comment: If you post an example of what you have I'll redo it with pdo

Comment: Ok, I think I've just understood it. Thanks!

Comment: Edited including the PDO version of your query even though you understand now.

Comment: Which mysql_fetch function is that?